# How to save map click coordinates (from module) in a global reactive list?

Tags: r, shiny, module

I'm using leaflet to plot a map and to get coordinates from user click.
Next, I want to save these coordinates in a global reactive list, so I can use these coordinates in another module. The problem is that I can't access the reactive list when it's placed on the server function (in app.R escope), neither outside the server function. The only way i found is to put the list of reactives inside the server function on the module server, so obviously is not global anymore.
How should I proceed? I want something like this (code below), so I can use the value saved in 'r' in all modules within the same session (not shared between sessions).

#### Map Module

```
mapModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  leafletOutput(ns('map'),  height="600px")
}

mapModuleServer <- function(input, output, session, r){
  
  # MAP plot #####
  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(width = '50 px', height = '50 px') %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-41.65, -22.0285, zoom = 10)
  })
  
  # # MAP LOGIC
  observe({
    click <- input$map_click
    leafletProxy('map') %>% removeMarker('pointClicked')
    if (is.null(click)){return()}
    leafletProxy('map') %>% addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat, layerId = 'pointClicked')
    r$lat <- click$lat %>% formatC(digits = 2, format = 'f')
    r$lon <- click$lng %>% formatC(digits = 2, format = 'f')
  })
} # end server function
```

### app.R

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'green',
      ....
              tabItem(tabName = "newGr",
                   box(mapModuleUI('mapa'))
              )
       ...
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues()
  callModule(mapModuleServer, 'mapa')
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I forgot to paste, the first lines in app.R are: library(shiny) library(shinydashboard) source('mapModule.R')

Comment: I think you just forgot the `r` in `callModule(mapModuleServer, 'mapa', r)`
Works great for me then

Comment: that's right @gdevaux. working in reactive environment is tricky! thank you!